# Best way to start a session dynamically from a URL

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, security, session, sinatra

I'm trying to create a session in Rails only when a user clicks on a button in their browser. What's the best way of going about this using jQuery?

**Practical uses for something like this might be:**

- Preventing an alert from displaying again once it's been closed.
- Remembering information about users at different stages.
- Saving basic one-time settings after an action has been completed.

I came up with this:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="startSession">Start a Session!</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#startSession").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/sessions-manager?add=funkysession"
  });
});
```

Then the **controller** would look something like:

```
get "/sessions-manager" do
  name = params[:add].to_sym
  session[name] = true  #=> session[:funkysession] = true

  # A session named "funkysession" has now been started
end
```

I feel this way is open to exploit, however. For example, people could manually punch in `/sessions-manager?add=user` and forge a user session to gain access to protected areas of my application. Is there a safer way to start sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two possible solutions to this problem.

**Option 1: Send Custom Headers In The AJAX Request**

The idea behind this is to set a custom HTTP header to be sent with the actual AJAX request, which will then be checked for in the controller. This means that people can't successfully interact with the `/sessions-manager` route manually in their web browser's URL bar. Custom headers can be set easily using jQuery:

```
$("#startSession").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/sessions-manager?add=showpassword",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar');}
  });
});
```

And now simply check that your custom header is present in the controller:

```
get "/sessions-manager" do
  if env["foo"] == "bar"
    // Add session
  else
    halt 401 // Authentication required error
  end
end
```

***A side note about this approach**: Whilst this certainly is an effective method of securing the `/sessions-manager` route, it can still be compromised. People who know what they're doing can forge HTTP headers using developer tools, so option 2 might be for you. Nonetheless, this is still a good strategy to implement as an extra layer of protection, just know its limits.*

**Option 2 (Preferred): Multiple Session Levels**

A far more effective solution that was brought to my attention by Bitcoin mastermind Sam Foley is to restrict the scope of session that can be created through the `/sessions-manager` URL. This can be achieved quite easily by adding another level to the session you want to create, that is - give the session a parent > child relationship. Check it out:

```
get "/sessions-manager" do
  session[:userprefs] ||= {} // Set parent session as empty hash
  name = params[:add].to_sym
  session[:userprefs][:name] = true
end
```

Much better. Now we can access this session anywhere in our application (views or controller):

```
if session[:userprefs][:showpassword] 
  "Password is blah"
end
```

More importantly people can't forge existing sessions. Someone trying to forge a user session, for example, will now create a session called `[:userprefs][:user]` which is effectively useless.

Comment: So... this isn't really doing anything. You're just using the existing Rails session mechanism in a very typical way. This isn't exactly news worthy.

Comment: Well no... The question was asking the best way to start a session through a URL without it being vulnerable to the application (eg - someone starting a fake use session). Sorry that my solution uses "the existing rails session mechanism". Maybe I should rewrite my answer using PHP's `$_SESSION[""]` functionality next time?

Comment: It wouldn't really matter, in either case, all you're doing is storing a value in the existing session mechanism, in a completely vanilla way, which is explicitly what said mechanism is for. I'm sorry, I really don't get what you're trying to do, or why it's novel.

Comment: I was not aware of being able to stack session hashes at the time of posting this question. I threw it in as an alternative to my jQuery solution because it's more secure, and, as a quick Google search would indicate not many rails developers know about it either.